# Setting minimum and maximum values of text box in VB .net 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to set **minValue** and **maxValue** of text boxes to define a range of acceptable values for validation purposes.

In VB 6 this is straight forward and can be done under text box properties, however in visual studio vb .net 2010 this is not the case or it may be the case that i am missing something.

Thanks,
Ayub

Comment: Are we talking about numbers here? Or Dates? Or ...?

Comment: Then go with LarsTech's answer

Comment: VB6's textbox has no such properties.  Nor does it make sense, a textbox edits text, not numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinForms, there is a NumericUpDown control that you can use, and it has properties for Minimum and Maximum.

Comment: Yes it works, but it would be great if i can set range of a text box without writing IF - ELSE i.e setting it under its properties :)

Comment: @Ayub That's what the Minimum and Maximum properies are for-- just set your values in there.

Comment: NumericUpDown Works great, but it has a Default Value (a number)... the problem is that data entry people may skip few numUpDown fields as they are already filled with a default value

Comment: @Ayub That's a different question than the one you posted.  You can always have a range of -1 to 50 and if it's -1, bug the user to enter a different number.

Comment: right! i had the same idea '-1' :D, normally the ranges are from 0 - 9, -1 could be used as a default empty value

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a numeric text box control with according properties. AFAIK MS does not provide one, but there are free solutions available like this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/HDNumericTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

make a customized textbox - thats checks the ascii of the entered value and - restrict the value to numeric., like - try with KeyDown or keypress events of text box and catch the keycode or event sender..

Comment: i am trying not to handle it with code, just like in VB6 there is option for Min/Max value for each text box

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [RangeValidator](http://sujaywa.blogspot.com/2010/06/range-validator-in-aspnet.html#.T3FGBeyolEg).

Comment: Please explain your answer why we should use it.